# Check if object excists in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I'm trying to create an Array with unique objects. I've got json data from a tounament that I want to order by pools. Each match got his own pooldata so he will push the pool data of each match to the array. This will create an Array of 5 of the same pool values. This is my code:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.objects.length; i++){
    obj = {
        poolId: data.objects[i].pool.id,
        poolLetter: data.objects[i].pool.name
    };

    if (arr.indexOf(obj) == -1) {
        arr.push(obj); 
    }else{} 
}
```

Comment: If you're creating a new `obj` in every loop turn with that object literal, the particular instance will never be an element of the array. `indexOf` uses `===`, which compares objects by identity, not by (custom) equivalence!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `obj` you are generating in the loop is not going to be the same object inside your `arr` array, they will have different signatures, so you can't use `indexOf` in this instance.

Instead, you will have to loop over the `arr` array to see if you can find any elements with the same `poolId` or `poolLetter`:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.objects.length; i++){
    obj = {
        poolId: data.objects[i].pool.id,
        poolLetter: data.objects[i].pool.name
    };

    // Do the insert if arr doesn't already contain this poolId    
    if(!arrayContains(arr, obj.poolId)) arr.push(obj);
}

// Helper function to find an instance of poolId in the given array
function arrayContains(arr, poolId) {
    for(var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
        if(arr[x].poolId === poolId) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhwfp/) which demonstrates the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array Prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype). Just pass the object.

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(obj) {
var i = this.length;
while (i--) {
    if (this[i] === obj) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Use the following

```
alert([1, 2, 3].contains(2)); //true
alert([1, 2, 3].contains('2')); //false
```

Answer (score 0):

indexOf compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict equality (the same method used by the ===, or triple-equals, operator).

then

`var obj1 = { a:1};`

`var obj2 = { a:1};`

`obj1 === obj2;  // wrong`

when you write "var obj1={a:1}" ,javascript create a new object.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a jQuery solution. I know you didn't asked for a jQuery answer. But maybe you want use it.

jQuery.inArray() returns the index of a specified value and returns -1 if not found.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/